# SSIS Excel Connection "No tables or views could be loaded"

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-connection-manager

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to connect to an Excel file source for a data flow. I have tried all of the following solutions found on StackOverflow and none of them work:

- Installed 32-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine for 2010 (I am running 32-bit version of Office)
- Changed Run64BitRuntime to "False"
- Delay Validation = "True" everywhere, inc the connection manager
- Changing the connection string to various suggestions found here and on other sites.
- Made sure the Excel file was closed.

I've connected to Excels sources successfully hundreds of times in other lives, but at this new job I've had to install VS myself and I've never had to do that before. Until now, the install has seemed fine and I can do plenty of other things without issue--I just can't connect to an Excel file source. I'm desperate. Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks to any who answer.

Error message I get:

"Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.
Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'"

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by uninstalling and then re-installing VS 2017. I suspect--but am not sure--that the key was to have the 32-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine for 2010 installed PRIOR to having the VS 2017 installed. That was not the case when I first installed VS 2017. But after uninstalling VS, I uninstalled then re-installed the 32-bit Access drivers, then reinstalled VS 2017 and my Excel connection worked fine. I also did all of the other steps outlined above prior to trying my connection, though I don't know if they were necessary.